# Is it possible to parse an XML file that resides within a nested zip archive from an octet-stream?

Tags: php, stream, zip

I am using the Transport For London (TFL) - Journey Planner Timetables API to get `stream.zip` from an octet-stream. Inside this archive are three more zipped directories; only one of the directory's is useful to me - in it resides a number of XML files I would like to parse in to a database.

Because I need to be able to update the database regularly - a minimum of 10 minutes - I would like to avoid having to download stream.zip to disk and instead read from and extract the necessary data.

stream.zip's structure is like so:

- stream.zip

  - Buses Part One.zip
  - Buses Part Two.zip
  - lultramdlrcablecarriver.zip **(Within resides the XML files I would like to parse.)**

Admittedly, I am new to working with streams and would like to keep things simple, but I feel there is a much smarter (less wasteful) way of consuming these XML files.

Please could someone with experience with streams ouline the steps involved in achieving the above? I am just after some direction. I am happy to then go off and read.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you have access to is the stream.zip, there's no way to only read a specific part of it. Your server needs the full file before opening it.

Comment: Are you sure? The reason I ask is because I spotted an interested example (#3), which can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: In the linked example (#3) the script will directly extract the specified file, it is avoiding to unzip the whole thing saving code lines and disk space. The problem is that you need the whole file before being able to read anything from it.